# Elementary Number Theory and Primitive Root

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a question about primitive root. The Problem is :

Prove that $3$ is a primitive root of $7^k$ ($k\ge 1$)

I try using mathematical induction on k.
But, I don't know how to solve it.
If you give me some hints, then I'll appreciate it :)
Thank you.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594782/2-is-a-primitive-root-mod-3h-for-any-positive-integer-h

Answer (score 2):

Using [Prove that a primitive root of $p^2$ is also a primitive root of $p^n$ for $n>1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332760/prove-that-a-primitive-root-of-p2-is-also-a-primitive-root-of-pn-for-n1?rq=1),

Let me denote ord$_ma$ to be [Multiplicative order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order) of $a\pmod m$

show that ord$_73=6=7-1$ i.e., $3$ is  a primitive root $\pmod7$

Again, from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170648/prove-that-any-primitive-root-r-of-pn-is-also-a-primitive-root-of-p/170759#170759),  we can prove ord$_{(7^2)}3=6$ or $7\cdot6$

But $\displaystyle3^6=729\not\equiv1\pmod{7^2}\implies$

ord$\displaystyle_{(7^2)}3=6\cdot7=\phi(7^2)$ i.e., $3$ is  a primitive root $\pmod{7^2}$