# Primitive Root modulo n n=98

Tags: number-theory, totient-function

I would like to make sure I am understanding this correcting.
My question is "Find primitive roots modulo $n$ using EGLF where $n=98$.

I have 
$\phi(98)=2(7^2)=98(1-\frac{1}{2})(1-\frac{1}{7})=42$
Since $(a,98)=1$ by EGLF $a^{\phi(n)} =a^{42}=1$.  Therefore the primitive roots mod $n$ are $a^{42}$ and $a^{84}$.  I'm saying $a^{84}$ because $42+42=84$ and is less then $98$.  Does this look right?

Comment: What does EGLF mean?

Comment: HAHA my bad, Euler's generalization of little Fermot

Comment: Let a∈Z and (a,n)=1 then a^(ϕ(n))=1 (mod n), moreover ord_n a | ϕ(n).

Comment: EGLF is usually called [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem).

Comment: See  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/754187/prove-that-3-is-a-primitive-root-of-7k-for-all-k-ge-1

Comment: I don't quite get it here: what is $\;a\;$, anyway? *Any* number coprime with $\;98\;$ ? It can't be, since $\;a=1\;$ trivially won't work, so what is it?

Comment: yah (a,98)=1 what what EGLF says.  a would be any number coprime with 98 by EGLF