# Is it possible to find a closed-form expression for $f(n)$?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, closed-form, discrete-logarithms

**QUESTİON UPDATED:**

Here is my problem:

> $$2^x \equiv a \pmod{3^n}.$$
>
> where, $a\not\equiv 0 \pmod{3}$ and $n\in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$

I want to learn that,

> If,
>
> $x=\left\{ {{3^n-\binom{n}{2}}-1}\right\}-f(n)$
>
> $a=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} 3^{n-j-1} 2^{3^j  - \binom{j+1}{2} -1}=2^{3^{n-1}-\frac {n(n-1)}{2}-1}+3\cdot2^{{3^{n-2}-\frac {(n-1)(n-2)}{2}-1}}+3^2\cdot2^{{3^{n-3}-\frac {(n-2)(n-3)}{2}-1}}+\cdots+3^{n-1}$

Is it possible to find a general solution that depends on $n$?

I found these values with algorithmic ways:

> $f(3)=16,f(4)=50,f(5)=94,f(6)=182,f(7)=400$

**The exact form of the problem is:**

> $$2^{\left\{ {{3^n-\binom{n}{2}}-1}\right\}-f(n)}\equiv 
>  \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} 3^{n-j-1} 2^{3^j  - \binom{j+1}{2} -1} \pmod{3^n}.$$
>
> **Question:** For $f(n)$ is it possible to find a closed-form expression depends on $n$ , which that $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ such that $f(n)\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}$ ?

**Small supplement:**

> Is it possible to find an algebraic closed form for  $n\to\infty$ ,  can the simpler function $f'(n)$ be found, which gives $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{ f(n)}{f'(n)}=1$ ?

I mean, for example, if  $f(n)=2^n+n^2+n$

We get, for $f'(n)=2^n.$

> Is something like this possible?

Comment: What is given and what is sought?

Comment: I want to solve for $x$.

Comment: Do you allow the discrete logarithm $\pmod{3^m}$?

Comment: Yes, this question related by discrete logarithm. But , some values are given.

Comment: ... then the problem is trivial.  $x = \log_2 a \pmod{3^m}$.  (Note that this is not the real logarithm, it is the [discrete logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm#Algorithms) modulo $3^m$.)

Comment: Now I will give an example in question.

Comment: Well, more or less by definition, $x$ **is** the discrete logarithm (of $a$ to the base $2$ in $\Bbb Z/3^n$). So I guess the question is: Is there a formula/method/algorithm to compute its value, for given $a$ and $n$?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg : Yes. Several general ones are listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm#Algorithms), a section of the page linked above.

Comment: @EricTowers: I was sort of aware of that, but wanted to help clarify the question first. So now, which of those algorithms would work "best" in this specific case (w.r.t. various interpretations of "best" maybe)?

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen  I'm waiting for 5 days for any word that will help me. Thank you very much for comment..Sorry, I could not understand Your Last comment..(english is my second language ) Is my question unclear? Is there a problem/issue in my question? Please, Could you make a comment again?

Comment: No problems with the question (I upvoted it). My suggestion was more about describing an "efficient" algorithm to do this in any numerical case. Your interest is undoubtedly in that specific sequence. I'm not sure that the method I outlined will serve that end well. That's why I asked whether you would find it at all helpful.  Checking Joffan's answer at all carefully now reveals to me that they had the same idea. I delete my earlier comments, and upvote Joffan's answer. All in the interest of thread hygiene :-)

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen Actually, to summarize the question, I am looking for an algebraic formula, for $f(n)$ which that, depends on $ n $.

Comment: Ok. It's clear now. But your $a$ is quite complicated :-). I'm a bit curious, why are you interested in this particular discrete log?

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen To tell you the truth, I did "research" about discrete logarithm .. Since I do not have mathematics education, sometimes I ask "nonsense" questions ..

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen apologize again for the inconvenience...I think If the sequence ($a$) were geometric, then it would be a solution..Do I think right?..

Comment: Ask https://math.stackexchange.com/users/44883/marko-riedel :P

Comment: @qwr please, would you do it for me?..

Comment: Wow, 29 edits. I think I'll wait until the question settles down.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson  What do you think about this question..? Would you like to comment? The idea You say can help me.. Thank you..:)

Comment: Now up to 38 edits! Student, if you can go one month without making any more edits, let me know, and I'll come back to have a look at the question.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson after a few days, 1 month will be complete...

Comment: Er, no; in one month, one month (since today's edit) will be complete.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson  OK :)) There is nothing to do ... I will wait for 1 month .. But, please tell me what you think about the question, 1 comment?.. Thank you..

Comment: Which of the 45(!) versions of the question would you like me to comment on? I have already told you, I will refuse to even glance at the question as long as you are changing it every couple of hours. When you can go a month without making any changes in the question, that's when I'll take it seriously.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson  Sorry, this was my last little edit..I will not make any more edits..Best Regards..

Comment: @Gerry Myerson  I assure you: I will not make any changes to the question for a month. The formulas I wrote in the question will never change. Please, help me, Teacher .. or I ask you to make at least 1 comment about the question.. Thank you very much..

Comment: 29 days to go...

Comment: @Gerry Myerson I understood, I will wait..

Comment: @Gerry Myerson  I'm so sorry...But I want to ask:  You have a answer about the question, but you want to explain it after a month.Or will You take the time to look at the question after only 1 month?... Thank You again..

Comment: What did I write, Student?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson I understood that you will answer the question after only one month. English is my second language..If I misunderstood you, I apologize. :(

Comment: @Gerry Myerson dear Teacher, I finished one month, as you want. Please tell me what I need to do now..      
 Best Regards.

Answer (score 9):

We know that there *is* a solution, since [$2$ is a primitive root for all powers of $3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594782/2-is-a-primitive-root-mod-3h-for-any-positive-integer-h).

For smallish values of $n$, we could solve this by iterating up the powers of three: solve $\bmod 3$ giving $x_1$, then calculate for the $3$ possible values $\bmod 9$, checking $x_1, x_1{+}2, x_1{+}4$ to find $x_2,$ then the $3$ possible values $\bmod 27$, $x_2, x_2{+}6, x_2{+}12$ to find $x_3$ etc. up to $x_n$.

At each step you have the (smallest) solution $x_k$ to $2^{\large{x_k}}\equiv a \bmod 3^k$. Then $x_k{+}\phi(3^k)$ and $x_k{+}2\phi(3^k)$ also solve this. Larger solutions will be greater than $\phi(3^{k+1})$ so one of these three values will be $x_{k+1}$, solving as the smallest solution to $2^{\large{x_{k+1}}}\equiv a \bmod 3^{k+1}$.

This process is relatively quick when you are using [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

For example this can quickly solve $2^x\equiv 4827836 \bmod 3^{17}$ as $x\equiv 16391041 \bmod \phi(3^{17})$. That is to say, $x = 16391041$ is the smallest solution and [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) means that you can add any multiple of $\phi(3^{17}) = 86093442$ for another valid result.

Your example of $2^x\equiv 8164718 \bmod 3^{15}$ solves to $x\equiv 5032989
\bmod \phi(3^{15})$.

Comment: Hmm..Can we say direct value of $x$?

Comment: $x\equiv 5032989
\bmod \phi(3^{15})=...?$ is $\phi$ euler totient function?

Comment: Correct, naturally any solution for $x$ will be $\bmod \phi(3^n)$ due to [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem). Here $5032989$ is the smallest positive $x$, and $\phi(3^{15})=2\cdot 3^{14} = 9565938$

Comment: @Student: There is no unique solution, if that is what you mean. What Joffan writes amounts to: The solutions to your example are $5032989, 5032989+\phi(3^{15}),5032989+2\phi(3^{15}),...$.

Comment: @Student A function-like expression? no, that isn't possible.

Comment: I understood thank you. ( I've already + 1)

Comment: There is one final question :) Is it possible to find $x$ by simple way , for so big value of $a$?

Comment: I guess that is a matter of perception. This seems like a simple way to me; certainly better than calculating every value of $2^x$ up to $\phi(3^n)$. It involves (at most) $3n$ calculations of $2^m \bmod 3^k$.

Comment: Thank you again, @Joffan.

Comment: I note that this method is [Hensel lifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma#Hensel_lifting) applied to the sequence of polynomials $u^{x_k} - a$, picking the lift that keeps $2$ as a root at each step.

Comment: We have only algorithmic solution (like a brute-force)  Right?

Comment: @EricTowers thanks for the official name, I thought it must be a known method.

Comment: @Student : Currently, yes.  The Hensel lifting says we're building a 3-adic number one digit at a time (after the first binary digit).  So each value of $a$ has an associated "3-adic" number.  For $a = 5$, that number is $0.85347378225213240809...$.  If you expand it with the mixed radix having place values $1/2, 1/6, 1/18, 1/54, 1/162, 1/486, ...$ the successive digits are the successive multiples of $\phi(3^k)$ that are selected for that step.  Currently, these numbers for each (odd) $a$ are mysterious.  (On the other hand, for $a = 16$, it's $1/3$.)

Comment: @Eric Towers I appreciate you sharing precious information. ( English is my second language. Sorry for Wrong words). (Generalized) For any discret logarithm problem, we have only algorithmic solution. Am I right? Or, Does that mean we have only algorithmic solution in Mathematics (in future)?

Comment: @Student:  Except for "trivial" problems, like $a = 2^y$ for small values of $y$, we only have algorithmic solutions.  The one here has the advantage that we get all solutions for $3^1, 3^2, \dots, 3^n$ for the same amount of effort.  But we do not know a direct method.  There is always hope that, in the future, someone will have insight into the hidden structure of the problem and find a more direct method.

Comment: @Joffan The question is a bit old, but I want to ask you.. You said that, finding a function-like expression is not possible.. But, I want to know that, Is it **mathematically impossible** to find such a function? Or, Is it just impossible for today's mathematics?..

Comment: @Student Not sure about mathematically impossible but the root steps are "random" in the sense of evenly distributed, so iterative searching like this is likely to be the only possibility unless some very special properties of this particular problem are found.

Comment: @Joffan I updated the question a few days ago .. Is there anything new you want to add to your answer?..

Comment: @Student I don't really understand the new version of the question; you have these very complicated forms of the exponent etc. that appear rather arbitrary. If I were to answer I would start a totally new answer for your revised question.

Comment: @Joffan Any Answer you give will be very helpful..