# Inference lifting a primitive root $\!\bmod p^n$ to $\!\bmod p^{n+1}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I was reading the second answer given in [2 is a primitive root mod $3^h$ for any positive integer $h$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594782/2-is-a-primitive-root-mod-3h-for-any-positive-integer-h)

However, I don't see the connection between this lemma and $2$ being a primitive root. Why are they equivalent? How can I prove? Any help is appreciated

> If $x$ is a primitive root $\!\bmod p^n$ and there's some $k$ such that $x^k\equiv1+p^n\pmod{p^{n+1}}$ then $x$ is a primitive root $\bmod p^{n+1}$.

Comment: The key point is that $k$ is special in that answer.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4372507/primitive-root-of-mod-n-and-mod-n1).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: apply the following, noting that the hypothesis excludes the first possibility $\,k = j$.

**Lemma** $ $ If $\,a\,$ has order $\,j,\,$ mod $\,p^n$ then $\,a\,$ has order $\,k = \color{#c00}j\,$ or $\,\color{#0a0}{pj},\,$ mod $p^{n+1}$

**Proof** $\,\ \ \ \ \ a^k\equiv 1\pmod{p^{n+1}}\,\Rightarrow\, a^k\equiv 1\pmod{p^{n}}\Rightarrow \color{#c00}j\mid k$

By [$\mu$LTE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3847038/242) $\:\!\ \ a^j\equiv 1\pmod{p^{n}}\Rightarrow a^{pj}\equiv 1\pmod{p^{n+1}}\Rightarrow k\mid \color{#0a0}{pj}$

Comment: Note: the $\,k\,$ above is not the same $\,k\,$ as in your hypothesis.